# handling state and event sequences of JDialog and JToggleButton

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, jtogglebutton, focuslistener

I am trying to build a `JToggleButton` that displays a `JDialog` (that contains a `JList`) when the `JToggleButton` is pressed. And have the `JDialog` disappear when the `JToggleButton` is pressed again, OR if the user clicks away or somewhere else in the frame (I simulated this via a `FocusListener` on the `JList` when the focus is lost).

Pressing the button in sequence will display and hide the `JDialog` correctly.

However, the problem is when the `JDialog` is visible, and I click somewhere else on the frame, the `JDialog` correctly disappears as the focus is lost. However, the state of the `JToggleButton` remains incorrectly set as selected. This meant that clicking on the `JToggleButton` now will not display the `JDialog` as the state of the `JToggleButton` is now out of sync. Instead, I will need to press the `JToggleButton` twice to get the `JDialog` visible again. My code example below demonstrates this issue.

I can't seem to get the lost focus of the `JList` to sync up with the state of the `JToggleButton`. It seems like a straightforward problem, but am stuck trying to find a solution. Can anyone help? Thanks.

See my code below:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

public class MultiComboBox extends JToggleButton
{
    public MultiComboBox(JFrame frame, String buttonText)
    {
        super(buttonText);

        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, false);
        dialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Object[] items = new Object[] { "one", "two", "three" };
        JList list = new JList(items);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        listScrollPane.setPreferredSize(list.getPreferredSize());

        dialog.add(listScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        dialog.pack();

        addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                final JToggleButton button = (JToggleButton) e.getSource();
                System.out.println("button clicked: " + button.isSelected());
                if (button.isSelected())
                {
                    Point p = button.getLocation();
                    p.setLocation(p.getX() + 300, p.getY());
                    SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, button);
                    dialog.setLocation(p);
                    dialog.setVisible(true);
                }
                else
                    dialog.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        list.addFocusListener(new FocusListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("list focusLost, dialog: " + dialog.isVisible());
                dialog.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        MultiComboBox mcb = new MultiComboBox(frame, "Toggle");

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 30));
        buttonPanel.add(mcb, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel blankPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(blankPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

- Don't add an ActionListener to the JToggleButton
- but instead add an ItemListener. This will respond to changes in the toggle's selection state
- Inside this listener, change the dialog's visible state.
- In your FocusListener, don't change the dialog's visible state but rather change the toggle's selection state.
- Use a WindowFocusListener added to the JDialog itself to be notified if it loses focus. This way the listener code can be outside of the code for the dialog components, a cleaner OOPs solution.

For example:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

public class MultiComboBox2 extends JToggleButton {
    public MultiComboBox2(JFrame frame, String buttonText) {
        super(buttonText);

        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, false);
        dialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Object[] items = new Object[] { "one", "two", "three" };
        JList list = new JList(items);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        listScrollPane.setPreferredSize(list.getPreferredSize());

        dialog.add(listScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        dialog.pack();

        addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                final JToggleButton button = (JToggleButton) e.getSource();
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    Point p = button.getLocation();
                    p.setLocation(p.getX() + 300, p.getY());
                    SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, button);
                    dialog.setLocation(p);
                    dialog.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    dialog.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });
        // addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        // @Override
        // public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // final JToggleButton button = (JToggleButton) e.getSource();
        // System.out.println("button clicked: " + button.isSelected());
        // if (button.isSelected()) {
        // Point p = button.getLocation();
        // p.setLocation(p.getX() + 300, p.getY());
        // SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, button);
        // dialog.setLocation(p);
        // dialog.setVisible(true);
        // } else
        // dialog.setVisible(false);
        // }
        // });

        list.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                System.out.println("list focusLost, dialog: " + dialog.isVisible());
                // dialog.setVisible(false);
                MultiComboBox2.this.setSelected(false);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        MultiComboBox2 mcb = new MultiComboBox2(frame, "Toggle");

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 30));
        buttonPanel.add(mcb, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel blankPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(blankPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but unfortunately this still is an issue. Using your sample code, the `JDialog` will disappear once the focus is lost, but it introduces a new problem where clicking on the `JToggleButton` now makes the `JDialog` visible all the time; instead of the previous behaviour where the `JDialog` appears and disappears as the `JToggleButton` is selected/unselected each time.